# Does LotusScript have an equivalent of this or self?

Tags: oop, object, lotus-notes, lotusscript

I'm trying to create an object in lotus notes and work in an OOP manor. Lotus script only kind of wants me to be able to do that.

One of the things I'm having a hard time finding is if classes in lotus script have any notion of themselves. In C# you can use the "this" keyword and python has the concept of self. Does lotus script have a similar concept?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LotusScript has the keyword `Me`to refer to the current class instance.

From IBM's e[xample code for the class construct](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/LSAZ_CLASS_STATEMENT_EX.html), you can see Me references on the last two lines of the `InvertColors()` method.

```
' Define a class.
Class textObject
   ' Declare member variables.
   backGroundColor As Integer
   textColor As Integer
   contentString As String
   ' Define constructor sub.
   Sub New (bColor As Integer, tColor As Integer, _
      cString As String)
      backGroundColor% = bColor%
      textColor% = tColor%
      contentString$ = cString$
   End Sub
   ' Define destructor sub.
   Sub Delete
      Print "Deleting text object."
   End Sub
   ' Define a sub to invert background and text colors.
   Sub InvertColors
      Dim x As Integer, y As Integer
      x% = backGroundColor%
      y% = textColor%
      Me.backGroundColor% = y%
      Me.textColor% = x%
   End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The IBM links is no longer valid as of Dec 2017.  A more direct answer can be found in the HCL docs at https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/11.0.1/basic/LSAZ_CLASS_STATEMENT.html under the section "Rules for referring to class members:" where it states:

You can use the keyword Me to refer to the object itself when you are inside a member procedure. In the example, Me.textColor refers to the value currently assigned to the textColor member of this instance of the class.